# How to get specific column value for a specific row value in AWK?

Tags: text-processing, awk

My folder structure looks like this:

```
$ tree
.
├── Original_folder
│   └── cat.txt
├── folderCD
│   └── cat.txt
├── folderGK
│   └── cat.txt
├── folderFE
    └── cat.txt
```

My `cat.text` file is like this

```
Version LRv1.10.0
Build date 2017-12-06
MOL-calc
PRESSURE
!                       
      Time[s]     InletT[K]   InletP[Pa]   O2_GasOut     C_GasOut
       100         0.001885   1070000       0.0007       0.2111  
       200         0.050885   1005000       0.0056       0.2171
       50          0.010885   1200000       0.0855       0.2411
and so on....
```

How to extract the column value with keyword in columnheader "_GasOut" for Time[s]=200?
How to extract the same data from all those cat.txt file and generate a new text file like this.....

```
Folder       Time[s]     O2_GasOut     C_GasOut 
Original_folder 200        0.0007       0.2111
FolderCD      200        0.0007       0.2111  
FolderGK      200        0.0056       0.2171
FolderFE      200        0.0855       0.2411
```

So far I tried to grab the column with `"_GasOut"` header.

```
gawk -F  $'\t' ' 
/_GasOut/{
   for(f=1;f<=NF;f++){
      # $a ~ "B" matches if string B is part of field $a
      # only these elements are taken to array colhdr
      if ($f ~ "_GasOut") colhdr[f]=$f
          print $f
   }
}
```

But it is not printing the columns f. And I don't know how to proceed further.
I wanted to have a new file(desired output text file) so that I can plot all the columns in separate graphs along with folder names in X axis. 
  I added one of the cat.txt file for reference. https://1drv.ms/t/s!Aoomvi55MLAQh1wMmpnPGnliFmgg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```bsh
awk '
    FNR==6 { for (n=1;n<=NF;n++) { if ($n ~ /_GasOut$/) cols[$n]=n; } }
    NR==6 {
        # print header
        printf "Folder Time[s]"
        for (c in cols) {
            printf " "c
        }
        printf "\n"
    }
    $1==200 {
        # extract foldername
        match(FILENAME, /^[^/]*/, folder);
        # print columns
        printf folder[0]" "$1
        for (c in cols) {
            printf " "$cols[c]
        }
        printf "\n"
    }
' */cat.txt | column -t -s' '
```

Output:

```
Folder           Time[s]  O2_GasOut  C_GasOut
folderCD         200      0.0056     0.2171
folderFE         200      0.0056     0.2171
folderGK         200      0.0056     0.2171
Original_folder  200      0.0056     0.2171
```

(I simply put the same file in all folders, that is why X_GasOut is the same for each row)

`column` command is optional to make a nice output.

Comment: That's hard coding about the column headers. I am sure about "Folder" and "Time[s]" but about other column headers (Those who have _GasOut as keywords) I don't know. I need to findout the name of the column headers.

Comment: better like this ? or do you mean you don't know if it will be $4 and $6?

Comment: It is not fixed that O2_GasOut header will be in the field 4 and C_GasOut header will be in the field 5. And there are unknown number of header with "_GasOut" keywords. And there positions are not fixed.
Please go to the provided link for the original cat file.

Comment: please review my update =)

Comment: It's only printing the column headers, but not the values of those columns.

Comment: not so for me, sure , that your input files have "Time[s]" on first column? Otherwise change the `$1==200` part accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake, It worked fine. Thanks

Comment: And how to mention specific folders, like take the folders with "RedKinMec" words in their names?

Comment: `awk '...' *RedKinMec*/cat.txt`

Comment: Please add an explanation of your script!

Comment: A small problem appears when the column headers are not arranged in the same sequence and when there is not equal number of column headers in files.